# Remedy poorly positioned black plastic edging

Tags: landscaping

I had 5", contractor grade, black, plastic edging installed but there are parts where it's exposed above the lip and some gaps behind it.

I pulled old plastic and removed brick to create the trench and it wasn't always even and the guy I hired I suspect cut corners a bit toward the end of the job because he was tired (human nature and nothing I can't fix).

1. What can I put behind the edging where there are gaps, more dirt, more gravel, or just leave it?
2. For the places where the edging is too high, it's staked.  Do I need to do anything?

I suppose my options are to leave it, mound up to it with dirt, move it downward by digging everything out and restaking it, or soak it with water and see if I can push it down.  My only concern with it being up too high is that I don't know how it will behave in the winter when things start freezing.

So, more concisely:

1. How do I fill gaps in edging on the yard side?
2. What should I do if my plastic edging is too high?

Comment: I cannot visualise what you are describing - can you please add photographs

Comment: sure.  I'll get some pics when I get home.